# Using a picker view based on what has been selected before

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, picker

I looked on here for an answer, but do not believe this question has been answered. I have multiple text boxes that use a couple different pickers. I would like for the first text box the user selects the material, and then based on the material selected they can only see the type of material that corresponds to it. Below in my code when I am naming my arrays you can see that it says typeBrassData or typeCopperData so if the user selects Brass or Copper above only the options for Brass show, does anyone know how to do this? Below is the code I was using when it was only 2 picker views. Thanks all in advance!

```
import UIKit

class MetalCalculatorViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var materialField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var typeField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var volumeField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var quantityField: UITextField!

var pickerMaterial = UIPickerView()

var pickerType = UIPickerView()


var materialData = ["Brass","Copper","CuNiSn", "Cupro-Nickel","High Performance Alloys", "Leaded Brass","Nickel Silvers","Phosphor Bronze","Tin Brass"]

var typeData = ["C101", "C102","C1092","C110","C122","C14415","C151", "C155","C18070", "C18080", "C19020", "C19025", "C19210","C194", "C195", "C197", "C1972", "C210","C220", "C226", "C230", "C240", "C260","C268","C272", "C350", "C353", "C422", "C425", "C4252", "C510","C511", "C5118", "C519","C521", "C638", "C654", "655", "C688", "C7025", "C70250", "C7026", "C7035", "C706", "C710", "C715", "C7250", "C752", "C757","C764","C770", "XP5", "XP10", "XP55", "XP125", "XP150", "XP175", "MAX251C", "MSP1"]

var typeBrassData = ["C210","C220", "C226", "C230", "C240", "C260","C268","C272"]
var typeHighPerformanceData = ["C14415","C151", "C155","C18070", "C18080", "C19020", "C19025", "C19210","C194", "C195", "C197", "C1972", "C638", "C654", "655", "C688", "C7025", "C70250", "C7026", "C7035", "XP5", "XP10", "XP55", "XP125", "XP150", "XP175", "MAX251C", "MSP1"]
var typeCopperData = ["C101", "C102","C1092","C110","C122"]
var typeCuproNickelData = ["C706", "C710", "C715"]
var typeLeadedBrassData = ["C350", "C353"]
var typeTinBrassData = ["C422", "C425", "C4252"]
var typePhosphorBronzeData = ["C510","C511", "C5118", "C519","C521"]
var typeCunNiSnData = ["C725"]
var typeNickelSilverData = ["C752", "C757","C764","C770"]

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pickerMaterial.delegate = self
    pickerMaterial.dataSource = self
    pickerMaterial.tag = 1

    materialField.inputView = pickerMaterial

    pickerType.delegate = self
    pickerType.dataSource = self
    pickerType.tag = 2

    typeField.inputView = pickerType

    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MetalCalculatorViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {



    if pickerView == pickerMaterial {
        return materialData.count

    } else if pickerView == pickerType{
        return typeData.count
    }

    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {


    if pickerView == pickerMaterial {
        return materialData[row]

    } else if pickerView == pickerType{
        return typeData[row]
    }
    return ""
}



func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView == pickerMaterial {
        materialField.text = materialData[row]
    } else if pickerView == pickerType{
        typeField.text = typeData[row]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `dictionary` data structure to set the values of the pickerviews

```
var materialSelected = ""

var typeArr = [String]()


//I have done for only three materials obviously you can extend it...

var dict = ["Brass" : ["C210","C220", "C226", "C230", "C240", "C260","C268","C272"],
            "Copper" : ["C101", "C102","C1092","C110","C122"], "CuNiSn" : ["C725"]] as [String: Any]

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {



  if pickerView == pickerMaterial {
        return materialData.count

    } else if pickerView == pickerType{
        typeArr = dict[materialSelected] as! [String]
        return typeArr.count
    }

    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {


    if pickerView == pickerMaterial {
        return materialData[row]

    } else if pickerView == pickerType{
        typeArr = dict[materialSelected] as! [String]
        return typeArr[row]
    }
    return ""
}



func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView == pickerMaterial {
        materialSelected = materialData[row]
        materialField.text = materialSelected

    } else if pickerView == pickerType{

        typeArr = dict[materialSelected] as! [String]
        typeField.text = typeArr[row]

    }
}
```